# FCM push notifications not working in AWS Lambda using Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I didn't find any questions that solved my issue, hence below:

This is the code I am using to send an FCM push notification via AWS Lambda written in Python. The AWS code is deployed on Lambda using the Zappa package:

```
# SENDING FCM NOTIFICATION
                        notification_headers = {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Authorization': 'key=' + serverToken,
                        }
                        body_en = {
                            'notification': {
                                    'title': post['src'],
                                    'body': post['title'],
                                    'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                                    'sound': 'default'
                            },
                            'to': deviceToken,
                            'priority': 'high',
                            'content_available': 'true',
                        }
                        response_en = requests.post(
                            "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", 
                            headers = notification_headers, 
                            data = json.dumps(body_en)
                        )
                        return response_en
```

Are there any imports I must do before being able to use FCM in AWS Lambda?

Comment: check if your lambda has internet access.

Comment: Yes it has - all the code prior to this handles http requests just fine. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: No, I am talking about, lambda connectivity, can you check lambda can connect to the internet means it can  anything out side the aws?

Comment: There's a parser in place prior to the FCM function, which is doing Beautiful Soup calls perfectly fine. Is there any other way to check lambda connectivity? Also the error I get from Zappa is a 400 Code while the body returned says <Response [400]>Runtime.MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable.

Comment: @MohammadSayeed, did you mean by following this? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/